# Docker Swarm: React frontend cannot connect to Kong API Gateway

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-swarm, kong

I am working on a project using microservices and I am trying to connect my frontend in React with my backend which is served through Kong API Gateway. The problem is that whenever I send a request to the server, I get the error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. The frontend service is running in the same network as the API Gateway service, but apparently, the DNS resolution is not working.

This is how I build the React frontend Docker image:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is how I send the request from the frontend:

```
handleLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Log in " + JSON.stringify(this.state.loginForm));
    axios.post(`http://${process.env.API_URL}:${process.env.API_PORT}/api/users/login`, this.state.loginForm)
      .then((response) => {
        const model: LoginModel = response.data;
        this.handleLoginResponse(model);
      })
      .catch((errors) => alert(`Error sending login request to server: ${errors}`));
  }
```

This is my stack.yml configuration file for Docker Swarm deployment:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    hostname: kong
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: "off"
      KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG: /usr/local/kong/declarative/kong-plugins.yml
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8443:8443
      - 8001:8001
      - 8444:8444
    volumes:
      - ../../Kong:/usr/local/kong/declarative
    networks:
      - frontend-network
      - internal
      - logging

  frontend-service:
    image: virusx98/frontend
    environment:
      API_URL: kong
      API_PORT: 8000
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    networks:
      - frontend-network

  [...] /* other services */

  
volumes:
  [...] /* volumes for other services */

networks:
  frontend-network:
  [...] /* other networks */

secrets:
  [...] /* secrets for other services */
```

The stack works perfectly on the backend side. If I send requests using Postman, they reach the backend services and a result is returned. But if I send requests from the frontend, the above error is thrown, even though both services are placed in the same network and DNS resolution should work. The environment variables are read correctly by the React service, but it says it cannot resolve hostname `kong`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your frontend image running node or being built to static files and served by something like nginx?

Comment: My image is running node, I edited this post, adding the Dockerfile used in building the image.

Comment: #1 Try  with another browsers to get more details of error. #2 Print this value to your log in react to ensure that url is what you expect: `http://${process.env.API_URL}:${process.env.API_PORT}/api/users/login` #3 In distributed environments like yours, frontend and backend are two different artifacts that can be consumed separately.  Try to invoke the same of your axios snippet but using postman or some http client. #4 I think your problem is related to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit based on comment

The reason you are unable to reach the API is because the Node process is not sending the request. Your browser is sending the request. The API must be accessible from your (and everyone else's) browser. In this case, your URL would need to be `localhost:8000` in your javascript, so that your browser will be able to reach the `kong` container.

### Original answer (only helps with env  vars)

react-scripts will only load a couple environment variables from Node. From their documentation:

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

This means you have to update `docker-compose.yml` like so:

```yaml
    environment: 
      REACT_APP_API_URL: kong
      REACT_APP_API_PORT: 8000
```

Doing this, and `console.log(process.env)` yields:

```json
{
  "NODE_ENV": "development",
  "PUBLIC_URL": "",
  "FAST_REFRESH": true,
  "REACT_APP_API_PORT": "8000",
  "REACT_APP_API_URL": "kong"
}
```

This being said, you should not use react-scripts start for production purposes. Always make a production build. You should instead add a `.env` file to your project so those variables get injected in the build. You won't be able to inject them via docker-compose.

### Reference:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: The problem is that I tried providing the URL and the port directly inside the code and the result is the same. Also, as long as I am concerned, Docker Swarm doesn't support .env files.